# C++ out of memory in python, plenty of space left

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, numpy, out-of-memory

I'm working on a project where I need to find Nearest Neighboors of am embedding vector. Recently, I'm tryng to use Google's new ANN tool SCANN [github](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/tree/master/scann).
I was able to create the searcher object and serialize it for an small dataset (~200K row with 512 values)
with the following code

```
import numpy as np
import scann
data = np.random.random((200k,512))
data = data / np.linalg.norm(data, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
searcher = scann.scann_ops_pybind.builder(data, 10, "dot_product").tree(
    num_leaves=2000, num_leaves_to_search=100, training_sample_size=250000).score_ah(
    2, anisotropic_quantization_threshold=0.2).reorder(100).build()
searcher.serialize('./scann')
```

But when I've tried with the real dataset (~48M rows with 512 values), I got:

```
In [11]: searcher.serialize('scann/')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-71a5ef71c81f> in <module>
----> 1 searcher.serialize('scann/')

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scann/scann_ops/py/scann_ops_pybind.py in serialize(self, artifacts_dir)
     70
     71   def serialize(self, artifacts_dir):
---> 72     self.searcher.serialize(artifacts_dir)
     73
     74

MemoryError: std::bad_alloc
```

The size of the `.npy`file for the dataset is ~90GB and I have at least 500GB of free RAM left on my computer and 1TB of free disk:

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and Python 3.6.9. The Scann module was instaled with Pip.

Any ideas of what can be going on?

Thanks for the help

[edit] After  @MSalters comment, I did some testing and find out that if the dataset to be serialized has more than 16777220 bytes (2^24+4) it fails with the `bad_alloc` message. I still don't know why this happens ...

[edit2] I build the SCANN from source, and put some debug prints in it. The error seems to be on this line:

```
vector<uint8_t> storage(hash_dim * expected_size);
```

and if I print it like this:

```
std::cout << hash_dim <<  " " << expected_size <<"\n" << std::flush;
std::cout << hash_dim * expected_size <<"\n" << std::flush;
vector<uint8_t> v2;
std::cout << v2.max_size() << "\n" << std::flush;
vector<uint8_t> storage(hash_dim * expected_size);
std::cout << "after storage creation\n" << std::flush;
```

Then I get;

```
256 8388608
-2147483648
9223372036854775807
```

Comment: One obvious question. Are you using a 32bit or 64bit version of Python? The 32bit version can only use 2GB of RAM.

Comment: The  output of `platform.architecture()` is `('64bit', 'ELF')`. I thought that could be the problem, but I just succeeded in serialized a dataset with 5M rows and 11GB, but failed with 10M rows and 21GB

Comment: It's pretty hard to get a `bad_alloc` on Linux. Linux will usually pretend that there is enough memory, even if there isn't. This is called overcommit, controlled by `proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`. The result of using unavailable memory is that Linux first grows slow (swapping) and then kills a random process. A `bad_alloc` hints more at a programming error, such as trying to allocate -1 bytes.

Comment: @MSalters I have done some testing and it seems that if my dataset's size is less than 16777126 (2^24) it works just fine. So I guess you're right and somewhere in the SCANN code the size of memory to be allocated  is overflowing a variable and then trying to alocate a negative amount of memory. Now i need just to find out where

Comment: Fire up gdb, put a breakpoint on `__cxa_throw`.

Comment: Looks like a bug in SCANN or the way it is used (not an expert on it so can't say for sure). The type of both [`hash_dim`](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/b663c6904f4f3800a8fe9766e60c9aba8429dffc/scann/scann/tree_x_hybrid/internal/utils.h#L41) and [`expected_size`](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/b663c6904f4f3800a8fe9766e60c9aba8429dffc/scann/scann/tree_x_hybrid/internal/utils.h#L37) is `int`, so `hash_dim * expected_size` overflows. `size_t` or `int64_t` would have worked better.

Comment: @rustyx I changed the types to  `long long int`, and justo to sure i did `long long int s = hash_dim * expected_size; vector<uint8_t> storage(s);` now if I print `s`the value is not overflowing, And the error disapeared, Thank you!

Comment: Good to hear. I posted an answer so that it's clearer to readers that the issue is solved.

Comment: Thanks! I will post the solution in the Github Issue, and eventually make a pull request with a fix.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an existing issue report in ScaNN, [#427](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/issues/427), with a similar error.

Based on the output of **`-2147483648`** for `std::cout << hash_dim * expected_size` we can conclude that `hash_dim * expected_size` overflows.

Looking at the source we see the type of both [`hash_dim`](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/b663c6904f4f3800a8fe9766e60c9aba8429dffc/scann/scann/tree_x_hybrid/internal/utils.h#L41) and [`expected_size`](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/b663c6904f4f3800a8fe9766e60c9aba8429dffc/scann/scann/tree_x_hybrid/internal/utils.h#L37) is `int`.

So probably the type of at least one of these should have been `int64_t`, `long long` or, better yet, `size_t`.

By looking at the source of ScaNN it seems there might be more places that could benefit from a data type specifically designed to hold a size (`size_t`) instead of an `int`.